# Is a qubit just a bit that hasn't been measured or observed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, waves, probability, superposition

A qubit is a superposition of a 0 and 1, apparently meaning that as long as the qubit isn't observed it is both 0 and 1, or a probability of being both. If this is the case, why don't regular bits turn into qubits given how we don't measure them or observe them? Or do we? If so, in what ways?

Answer (score 1):

It is common in popularizations to say things like "the qubit is in a state that is a mixture of 0 and 1 until we observe it" etc. That makes it sound it is like a classical bit that just happens to be a bit indeterminate. But if that was the only difference quantum computing would not be particularly interesting or powerful.

Qubits can not just be in superposed states, but they can also be entangled. The state of two entangled qubits is a probability distribution over all possible combinations. This produces all sorts of complicated effects if you measure one but not the other. Also, quantum operations manipulate these probability distributions in complex ways.

Most deeply, quantum mechanics seem to imply that qubits in superpositions truly do not have any state beyond whatever the probability distribution describes. While classical bits may have states that are unknown to you, but retain a definite state. So the unwatched classical bit is different from the unwatched qubit.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics is often misrepresented in popular treatments. If a quantum system is undergoing interference or entanglement and information is copied out of it, then the quantum effects will be suppressed: this is called decoherence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072

It doesn't matter whether we call that information transfer a measurement or not. It doesn't matter if a person or a computer or whatever is looking at the result and interpreting it. All that matters is whether information is copied. A bit in a standard computer interacts with its environment, which copies information out of the bit, so it suffers decoherence.